# I need to create a custom search bar for android app

Tags: java, android

I want to create a custom search bar that appears at the top of my app that I can use to search items in a list of objects....the objects are plotted to a map and there is also a list textview where all the information is displayed.the user can switch between the map view and the list view...I have tried some ideas given to me but that don't work any help would be appreciated.

mainActivity

```
package com.vuvucall.maptest;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    ArrayList<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    FrameLayout mapsLayout;
    Button loadDataButton;
    boolean listLoad = true;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView recycleView;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;
    private Context context;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);



//       EditText editText = findViewById((R.id.search_text));
//
//        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
//            @Override
//            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
//            }
//            @Override
//            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
//            }
//            @Override
//            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
//            {
//                //filter(editable.toString());
//            }
//        });




        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mapsLayout = findViewById(R.id.mapsLayout);
        loadDataButton = findViewById(R.id.loadDataButton);
        recycleView = findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recycleView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        loadDataButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (listLoad) {
                    listLoad = false;
                    mapsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recycleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    loadMapsData(mItems);
                    loadDataButton.setText(getString(R.string.show_list));

                } else {
                    listLoad = true;
                    mapsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recycleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    loadListData(mItems);
                    loadDataButton.setText(getString(R.string.show_maps));
                }



            }



        });



    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
//        int id = item.getItemId();
//
//        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        this.googleMap = googleMap;

        new ProcessInBackground().execute();


    }


    public class ProcessInBackground extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<Item>> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        Exception exception = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Busy loading rss feed...please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Item> doInBackground(Integer... params) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://quakes.bgs.ac.uk/feeds/MhSeismology.xml");

                //creates new instance of PullParserFactory that can be used to create XML pull parsers
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

                //Specifies whether the parser produced by this factory will provide support
                //for XML namespaces
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

                //creates a new instance of a XML pull parser using the currently configured
                //factory features
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                // We will get the XML from an input stream
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

                /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
                 * We should take into consideration that the rss feed name is also enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
                 * Every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title> etc."
                 * We should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
                 * and take into consideration only the "<title>" tag which is a child of the "<item>" tag
                 *
                 * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable called "insideItem".
                 */
                boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, START_DOCUMENT, END_DOCUMENT etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType(); //loop control variable

                Item item = null;
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    //if we are at a START_TAG (opening tag)
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        //if the tag is called "item"
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            insideItem = true;
                            item = new Item();
                        }
                        //if the tag is called "title"
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            if (insideItem) {
                                // extract the text between <title> and </title>
                                item.setTitle(xpp.nextText());
                            }
                        }
                        //if the tag is called "link"
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                            if (insideItem) {
                                // extract the text between <link> and </link>
                                item.setLink(xpp.nextText());
                            }
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:lat")) {
                            if (insideItem) {
                                //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                                item.setLat(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));
                            }
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:long")) {
                            if (insideItem) {
                                //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                                item.setLon(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //if we are at an END_TAG and the END_TAG is called "item"
                    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = false;
                        mItems.add(item);
                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                exception = e;
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                exception = e;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                exception = e;
            }

            return mItems;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Item> s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);


            // ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mItems);
            // lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            loadDataButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadListData(s);
        }
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        try {
            //openConnection() returns instance that represents a connection to the remote object referred to by the URL
            //getInputStream() returns a stream that reads from the open connection
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void loadMapsData(ArrayList<Item> listData) {

        int i = 0;

        for (Item item : listData) {

            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(item.getLat(), item.getLon()))
                        .title(item.getTitle())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            } else if (i % 5 == 1) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(item.getLat(), item.getLon()))
                        .title(item.getTitle())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            } else if (i % 5 == 2) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(item.getLat(), item.getLon()))
                        .title(item.getTitle())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
            } else if (i % 5 == 3) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(item.getLat(), item.getLon()))
                        .title(item.getTitle())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
            } else if (i % 5 == 4) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(item.getLat(), item.getLon()))
                        .title(item.getTitle())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET)));
            }

            i++;



        }


        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        //the include method will calculate the min and max bound.
        for (Item item : listData) {
            builder.include(new LatLng(item.getLat(), item.getLon()));
        }


        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        int padding = (int) (width * 0.10); // offset from edges of the map 10% of screen

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);

        googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
    }

    private void loadListData(ArrayList<Item> listData) {
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(context, listData);
        recycleView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    }





}
```

item.java

```
package com.vuvucall.maptest;

public class Item {
    private String title;
    private String link;
    private Double lat;
    private Double lon;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (new StringBuilder()).append("title: \n").append(title).append("\n")
                .append("link: ").append(link).append("\n")
                .append("geo-lat: ").append(lat).append("\n")
                .append("geo-lon: ").append(lon).toString();
    }
}
```

item_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#f4ffe7"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="23.4, 34.8"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/latlon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ListAdapter.java

```
package com.vuvucall.maptest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListDataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<Item> itemList;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       // two types of view. One is title of group and other is item view
        return position;
    }

    public ListDataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> events) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList =events;


    }




    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


                View viewTWO = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
                MainViewImage rowTWO = new MainViewImage(viewTWO);
                return rowTWO;

    }


    public class MainViewImage extends MyViewHolder {


        LinearLayout rootView;
        TextView title,latlon;



        public MainViewImage(View v) {
            super(v);

            rootView = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            latlon = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.latlon);


        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final Item event= itemList.get(position);
        final MainViewImage mainHolder = (MainViewImage)holder;


        mainHolder.title.setText(event.getTitle());
        mainHolder.latlon.setText("Latitude: "+event.getLat()+" , Longitude: "+event.getLon());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }


}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="right"/><!--gravity of a edit text-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/show_maps"
                android:id="@+id/loadDataButton"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <include android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have created an edit text object and I tried to create a function that would search through the list of items but I kept getting incompatibility issues then all my code in the main activity had errors..i'm pretty stumped.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: thanks I have added some code and some more explanation